# using mysqli to retrieve only 1 row record

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE listName = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $listName = '$_POST[lname]';
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $listName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->close();
}
    if ($count>0)
{//do some insert}
else 
{echo "exist , <a href="">back</a>";}
```

Can it check whether the row exist? Are there any more elegant way to do this? thanks

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE listName = ?");
$listName = $_POST['lname'];
$stmt->bind_param("s", $listName);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
try {
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0 ) {
         throw new Exception('The list name is existed');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   echo '<br />';
   exit('<a href="">back</a>');
   $stmt->close();
}
```

After correction, is it correct? Because it just fall into the list name is existed

Comment: well drop the count just grab the id, otherwise its standard.

Comment: what does it mean of the id??? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
try {
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 0 ) {
         throw new Exception('There is no records');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   echo '<br />';
   exit('<a href="">back</a>');
}
```

Comment: still some problem , please have a look

Comment: `$listName = '$_POST[lname]';` -> `$listName = $_POST['lname'];`
instead `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE listName = ? LIMIT 1` use `SELECT * FROM list WHERE listName = ?`

Comment: thanks, and last question, for any insert , can i use try - catch to detect error? what is / are the common error when insert? (i have checked connection error)

Comment: you can use try - catch for any error or unexpected behavior. There is no common error - for each person differently. I advice switch mysqli driver to PDO(more faster, more features). Also DB-way to check on empty: http://pastebin.com/cAduMeDM